# Make a vector of comparator functions

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, std-function

My problem is to test an implementation of quicksort with different comparator functions: `std::less` and `std::greater`. But I do not want to copy-paste testing code that differs just in two comparators, so I would like to put them into a vector (or maybe something else?) and iterate over them.

To simplify this post, lets say I would like to write a loop over a vector of two functions that get `0` and `1` as their arguments and output a boolean. Here is my take at that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    auto fs = std::vector<>{std::less<int>{}, std::greater<int>{}};

    for (auto f: fs) {
        std::cout << f(0, 1) << " ";
    } std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

My `g++ 6.1.1` compiler rightfully complains that I have not specified the template arguments for the vector. I have been trying things like `std::function<bool(int, int)>` and others with no luck.

Could you tell me how to fix this piece of code?

---

Update: The exact error I am getting:

```
% g++ -std=c++14 -Wall deleteme.cpp && ./a.out
deleteme.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
deleteme.cpp:6:27: error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be at least 1)
     auto fs = std::vector<>{std::less<int>{}, std::greater<int>{}};
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.1.1/vector:64:0,
                 from deleteme.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/6.1.1/bits/stl_vector.h:214:11: note: provided for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
     class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
           ^~~~~~
deleteme.cpp:8:18: error: unable to deduce ‘auto&&’ from ‘fs’
     for (auto f: fs) {
                  ^~
```

Comment: Can you add your compilation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only from C++17, template arguments of the constructor can be used to deduce the template arguments of the type, so you will have to write `std::vector<std::function<bool(int,int)>>` instead of `std::vector<>`.

Please note that `std::function` has a performance overhead compared to calling functions directly, so you might want to check out variadic template arguments (and [swallowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276991/variadic-template-arguments-unpacking)) for getting the last few percentages

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added `std::function<bool(int, int)>` back into vector and it worked. I could swear it did not work 30 mins ago.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your second paragraph about `std::greater<int>`, `std::greater<int>{}` and `std::greater<int>()`? For me, the first is just a type, the second and the third are calling default constructors for the `struct std::greater<int>` and do not differ. Do they differ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, that is wrong. I'm used to work with a codebase which has similar concepts as the STL and sometimes mix them up. std::greater is indeed a struct, not a free function.

Answer (score 0):

As you use different types, you might use tuple, and iterate over tuple:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename F, typename TUPLE, std::size_t ... Is>
    void run_for_each(F&& f, TUPLE&& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        const int dummy[] = {0, (f(std::get<Is>(std::forward<TUPLE>(t))), void(), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
    }
}

template <typename F, typename TUPLE>
void run_for_each(F&& f, TUPLE&& t)
{
     detail::run_for_each(std::forward<F>(f),
                          std::forward<TUPLE>(t),
                          std::make_index_sequence<
                              std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TUPLE>>::value>());
}
```

And then

```
int main() {
    auto t = std::make_tuple(std::less<int>{}, std::greater<int>{});

    run_for_each([](auto&&f) {std::cout << f(0, 1) << " ";}, t);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/7qBmzn)